# Arranging elements in a vector by their status

Tags: c++, boost

Let's have simplified class:

```
class A
{
   bool val_;
   public:
     A() : val_(true) {}
     bool isNew() const { return val_; }
     void setDirty() { val_ = false; }
};
```

and the vector of objects of such class:

```
vector<A> coll;
coll.push_back(A());
coll.push_back(A());
coll.push_back(A());
coll.push_back(A());
coll[1].setDirty();
coll[3].setDirty();
```

I need some elegant solution to rearrange(sort) elements in the vector, so that not modified objects will be grouped at the beginning of the sequence.

Comment: Please compile before posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Partition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/) algorithm from standard library for that:

```
bool MyPredicate(A& a) { return a.isNew();}
...
// bound is iterator pointing to the first element for which predicate returns false
vector<A>::iterator bound = partition(coll.begin(), coll.end(), MyPredicate);
```

Or, as Christian Rau suggested solution without separate function:

```
std::partition(coll.begin(), coll.end(), std::mem_fun_ref(&A::isNew))
```

Comment: +1 The only one not suggesting `std::sort`, which may be overkill for this simpler problem. And you also get the start of the second group. Maybe a little code sample would make it an even more attractive alternative to the other sort-based answers.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I agree that `partition` sounds like the most appropriate algorithm, but I wonder how it would differ from `sort` in terms of complexity in this particular situation (and bear in mind that we don't use `stable_sort`).

Comment: With the help of `std::mem_fun_ref` you don't even need a separate function. And I also don't think you need to negate, as he wants the `true` ones first. So just do `std::partition(coll.begin(), coll.end(), std::mem_fun_ref(&A::isNew))`. This would be the most elegant C++03 has to offer, I think.

Comment: @KerrekSB It doesn't matter if it is more efficient than `std::sort`, as it should obviously not be less efficient and **could** be more efficient. But the main thing is, it's just more suited, as it only does what is neccessary and is therefore a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about `sort`:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::sort(coll.begin(), coll.end(),
     [](const A & a, const A & b) -> bool { return a.isNew() < b.isNew(); } );
```

You'll have to rewrite the class to declare `isNew()` as `const`.

For older compilers, use a function instead of the lambda:

```
bool isNewCompare(const A & a, const A & b) { return a.isNew() < b.isNew(); }
std::sort(coll.begin(), coll.end(), isNewCompare);
```

*Edit:* @Vladimir has the better answer, `std::partition()` is the more appropriate algorithm for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` lets you provide a custom comparison function object. You define a class that overrides the paranthesis operator, and returns true if the first argument should come before the right argument:

```
class COrderByDirty
{
   bool operator(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) const 
   {
       // Says lhs should come before rhs only if 
       // lhs is marked as dirty, and rhs is not
       if (lhs.GetDirty() < rhs.Dirty())
       {
           return true;
       }
   }
 }
```

Then simply instantiate it use it to sort:

```
 std::sort(coll.begin(), coll.end(), COrderByDirty());
```

If you can use C++11, you can avoid the lengthy class creation and use a lambda, as Kernek does in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::sort` from `<algorithm>` together with `boost::bind`. It could look something like this:

```
std::sort(coll.begin(), coll.end(), boost::bind(&A::isDirty, _1));
```

Assuming `A` has a function `bool A::isDirty() const`.

This works because you use the following ordering predicate implicitly:

```
bool cmp(const A &a, const A &b) {
    return a.isDirty();
}
```

We just don't care what happens when both are dirty or both are not dirty.

Comment: `boost::bind` isn't necesarry

Comment: krynr, John, have either of you tested your proposed versions?

Comment: Why not? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Thanks Kerrek, I forgot the `&`.

Comment: @krynr Because you need a binary (ordering) predicate and not just a unary one. Look at the other answers for a correct sort-based version.

Comment: @ChristianRaus: Or you could just ignore the second argument (in this case at least). It might look wired, but it works.

Comment: @krynr Ha, nice one. Now that I see it it's a nice idea. But I'm not sure if this would be a strict weak ordering. Couldn't this result in cases where a<b and b<a (when both are `true`). It may not disturb the algorithm in practice, but I think the standard demands a strict weak ordering (< and not <=).

Comment: @ChristianRau: You're right of cause, the ordering is not asymmetric. So it depends on the implementation of sort and the input whether this somehow backfires or not.